# jquery datepicker not working while resizing the browser view

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The jquery picker and the select option works well when it is on the full-screen desktop. But when I resize the browser view, nothing shows up when I click on them. 
This is the link: http://www.yiyalo.com 
here is the source code: https://github.com/stephenleong/MyProject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with the JQuery. you made a mistake in using BootStrap's grid. there is a "col-md-1" in your page which expands in mobile view and covers the form controls. you need to rewrite your grid. take a look at [BootStrap's Grid system](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)